# SQL Server 2008 R2 Cluster Service pack 3 fail to failover node

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, clustering, service-pack

I have a SQL Server R2 cluster on Windows 2008 R2 boxes, and today i was to install SP3. I installed it without any errors and rebooted the passive node.

When i then try to failover to the passive node it fails. I get this from the Log

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        MSSQLSERVER
Date:          2015-03-24 18:38:45
Event ID:      19019
Task Category: Failover
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      computername.domain.se
Description:
[sqsrvres] OnlineThread: SQLClusterResourceWorkerWaitForCompletion failed (status 0)

Event Xml:

  
    
    19019
    2
    3
    0x80000000000000
    
    16109747
    Application
    computername.domain.se
    
  
  
    [sqsrvres] OnlineThread: SQLClusterResourceWorkerWaitForCompletion failed (status 0)

    4B4A0040010000000D0000005700460041004C0049005400450043004C00300031003400000000000000
```

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering
Date:          2015-03-24 18:38:45
Event ID:      1205
Task Category: Resource Control Manager
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      computername.domain.se.se
Description:
The Cluster service failed to bring clustered service or application 'Computername' completely online or offline. One or more resources may be in a failed state. This may impact the availability of the clustered service or application.
Event Xml:

  
    
    1205
    0
    2
    3
    0
    0x8000000000000000
    
    369312
    
    
    System
    computername.domain.se.se
    
  
  
    computername
```

If i failback to the unpatched node, i get the resorces online without problem. But the patched node just keep on failing.

Does anybode have an idea on where i should start diggning?

Comment: I did a rollback of the servicepack on the passive node and managed to get the resources online again on that node. I'll leave it with that for now, but i still would like to know if someone has any tips.

Comment: there should be more errors in the event log. look at the sql server log. look at the cluster event log. post more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after a long time. It was due to 1 million+ files in the \MSSQL\log folder.

After setting up a job that cleared that folder. The failover after SP install worked fine.

The solution was confirmed on both this 2008R2 cluster, and the 2012 cluster we had the same problem on.